# populate select based on another select php arrays

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a nested php array. I have the first select populated already. I want the second select populated with values of the php array based on selected option, which is the key in my php array. I have checked other posts, and they just seem way too complex for me to understand and/or implement. I think you'll understand once you see it:

```
<?php

$books = array(
    "លោកុប្បត្តិ"=> range(1,50),
    "និក្ខមនំ"=> range(1,40),
    "លេវីវិន័យ"=> range(1,27),
    "ជនគណនា"=> range(1,36),
    "ចោទិយកថា"=> range(1,34),
    "យ៉ូស្វេ"=> range(1,24),
    "ពូកចៅហ្វាយ"=> range(1,21),
    "នាងរស់"=> range(1,4),
    "សាំយូអែល ទី១"=> range(1,31),
    "សាំយូអែល ទី២"=> range(1,24),
    "ពង្សាវតារក្សត្រ ទី១"=> range(1,22),
    "ពង្សាវតារក្សត្រ ទី២"=> range(1,25),
    "របាក្សត្រ ទី១"=> range(1,29),
    "របាក្សត្រ ទី២"=> range(1,36),
    "អែសរ៉ា"=> range(1,10),
    "នេហេមា"=> range(1,13),
    "នាងអេសធើរ"=> range(1,10),
    "យ៉ូប"=> range(1,42),
    "ទំនុកដំកើង"=> range(1,150),
    "សុភាសិត"=> range(1,31),
    "សាស្ដា"=> range(1,12),
    "បទចំរៀងសាឡូម៉ូន"=> range(1,8),
    "អេសាយ"=> range(1,66),
    "យេរេមា"=> range(1,52),
    "បរិទេវ"=> range(1,5),
    "អេសេគាល"=> range(1,48),
    "ដានីយ៉ែល"=> range(1,12),
    "ហូសេ"=> range(1,14),
    "យ៉ូអែល"=> range(1,4),
    "អេម៉ុស"=> range(1,9),
    "អូបាឌា"=> range(1,1),
    "យ៉ូណាស"=> range(1,4),
    "មីកា"=> range(1,7),
    "ណាហ៊ុម"=> range(1,3),
    "ហាបាគុក"=> range(1,3),
    "សេផានា"=> range(1,3),
    "ហាកាយ"=> range(1,2),
    "សាការី"=> range(1,14),
    "ម៉ាឡាគី"=> range(1,3),
    "ម៉ាថាយ"=> range(1,28),
    "ម៉ាកុស"=> range(1,16),
    "លូកា"=> range(1,24),
    "យ៉ូហាន"=> range(1,21),
    "កិច្ចការ"=> range(1,28),
    "រ៉ូម"=> range(1,16),
    "កូរិនថូស ទី១"=> range(1,16),
    "កូរិនថូស ទី២"=> range(1,13),
    "កាឡាទី"=> range(1,6),
    "អេភេសូរ"=> range(1,6),
    "ភីលីព"=> range(1,4),
    "កូល៉ុស"=> range(1,4),
    "ថែស្សាឡូនីច ទី១"=> range(1,5),
    "ថែស្សាឡូនីច ទី២"=> range(1,3),
    "ធីម៉ូថេ ទី១"=> range(1,6),
    "ធីម៉ូថេ ទី២"=> range(1,4),
    "ទីតុស"=> range(1,3),
    "ភីលេម៉ូន"=> range(1,1),
    "ហេព្រើរ"=> range(1,13),
    "យ៉ាកុប"=> range(1,5),
    "ពេត្រុស ទី១"=> range(1,5),
    "ពេត្រុស ទី២"=> range(1,3),
    "យ៉ូហាន ទី១"=> range(1,5),
    "យ៉ូហាន ទី២"=> range(1,1),
    "យ៉ូហាន ទី៣"=> range(1,1),
    "យ៉ូដាស"=> range(1,1),
    "វិវរណៈ"=> range(1,22)
);

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function OnChange(dropdown)
{
  //reload page after drop down selection
  dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="foo"></div>

<div id="links">

<form action="">
<select name="chapter">
<?php
foreach ($books as $key => $value) {
    echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $key . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<br>
<select name="book">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a very easy script called "Chained Selects jQuery Plugin". This ofcourse is just in case you would use javascript + jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a try in a bit and let you know how it works out.